# Unable to publish messages from JMeter to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: jmeter, activemq-artemis

I'm trying to run a JMS load test from JMeter. The target server is ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16.0.
I've configured the JMS Publisher as follows:

[image]

Although the Destination "queueDemo" has been created in the broker, the following error is reported in the Result Tree: "Response message: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: queueDemo"

Am I missing something in my configuration?
Aside from that, I have added the file artemis-jms-client-all-2.16.0.jar in the "lib" folder of JMeter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `dynamicQueues/` prefix for your destination `queueDemo` since you're not defining it in your JNDI properties, e.g.:

```
dynamicQueues/queueDemo
```

Read more about the ActiveMQ Artemis JNDI implementation and how to use it in [the documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html#destination-jndi).

Answer (score 1):

Besides what @Justin mentioned, you can also package the [jndi.properties](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/using-jms.html#destination-jndi) in a jar file and place it into the "lib" folder of JMeter.